# How to create a MsWord (.doc) file from php that spans more than one page (using html)

Tags: html, ms-word

i need to create a .doc file that has more than one page. I want to create the doc file from html (setting the headers so that it is interpreted as a doc file) but i don't know how to add a page break in html that is correctly recognized from word.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may find [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com/) to be useful.

> PHPWord is a library written in PHP
>   that create word documents.

**Update:**

**Method One:**

[Here is a method using COM](http://www.rawseo.com/news/2009/06/11/how-to-create-microsoft-office-documents-with-php/) (requires Word  to be installed)

**Method Two:**

Use appropriate headers, here is an example:

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=document_name.doc");

echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<b>My first document</b>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
```

Comment: Cool. But it creates .docx files, not .doc. I was looking forward to seeing PHP code that generates a .doc file. Still, nice to know PHPWord is there.

Comment: @alcuadrado: You are right but now i have updated my answer :)

Comment: @sAc, method two is what i meant. I was just wondering if there was an html tag that would interpreted by MsWord as a page break!

Comment: Actually the best way to do what i wanted to do is to create an html file on the server, pass it to the open-office converter to create a .doc file and then send it back to the client! Thx for your posts!

Comment: @Nicola Peluchetti: Page break works with `<br clear=all style='page-break-before: always'>`